# Backup Time Capsule to 'cloud' / online backup provider

Tags: backup, time-capsule

I've got a 3 TB Time Capsule that stores a range of files and Time Machine backups. I’d like to be able to backup the whole Time Capsule offsite, ideally using a "cloud" backup provider.

The Time Capsule itself is a stand alone unit (not tethered to any machine). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to do a second time capsule backup to the cloud.  As long as you can specify the location "as a folder" to time machine, then you have time machine making 2 backups for you.

I do 2 backups, one to the Airport Time Capsule unit and one to a different network drive.  I know it is not in the cloud, but if you can do as I mentioned above, that is another way to do it.

I also use SOS backup to the cloud.  If I specify the time machine backup folder, it will do exactly as you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not used this product on a Mac, nor in this particular way, it *should* work.

there is a product called [Syncovery](https://www.syncovery.com/overview/) which will backup selected files to "FTP, SSH, HTTP, WebDAV, Amazon S3, Google Drive, Microsoft Azure, SugarSync, box.net and many other cloud storage providers". We use it successfully to copy backups from a local server to our Amazon S3 account.

I would imagine that you could tell Syncovery what source to use and it would back up your time capsule to Amazon S3 (or other). As I have not used this specific app for this specific function I would recommend asking their tech support to verify if this is something they support.

Note I have no financial interest in this company, just a satisfied user of their (PC) product.