# How to restore deleted files from an internal HDD which has just undergone a full disk format?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, restore, disk-format

I was recently restoring macOS from one partition to the other during which all files got corrupted.

Since none of the files were opening I did a complete format and reinstalled macOS

Now my question is how can I recover all my files (properly) without the help of any recovering software!

Comment: If you don't have a backup then you are out of luck.

Comment: Real men don't do backups! Real men also often cry...

Comment: I don't have a backup and most recovery suggests fail to recover files entirely and files get corrupted while recovering and the disk wasn't encrypted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my question is how can I recover all my files (properly) without
>   the help of any recovery software!

You can't.  Unless you have the skill to read/edit the partition tables as well as search each and every sector for orphaned blocks which you will then rebuild, you *must* use recovery software.

Additionally, that's predicated on if it's a traditional (spinning) hard disk.  If it's an SSD, the data is gone.

You will also want to review this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308563/119271) on backups