# Backup to two sources (external HDD and network folder) at the same time

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, imac

**My setting:**

I use a iMac 27” Retina 5K with macOS 10.15 Catalina

At the moment, I use the Time Machine to make a backup to an external HDD.

For safety reason, I would like to save a copy of my Time Machine backup to a local network folder that is connected to my iMac.

**My questions:**

What is the savest way to do so?

Can I set up the Time Machine to make two backup's (HDD and local network folder) at once?

**Update:**

I just learned that a series of backups is probably not the best solution.
I think about to sync all data to the network folder. Is there any in-built program in macOS to do so?
If not, what software would you recommend? If I could chose I would prefer an encrypted sync.

Comment: You're basically making a backup of a backup which should be avoided.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308563/119271

Comment: Dear Allan. Thank you for your precious advice. I updated my question.